# Check for collision with side of screen

Tags: java, swing, collision

I thought of a program where you move a square with the arrow keys. I created it and [asked a question about it on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226301/jpanel-size-is-not-known-on-start).

I copied the last code block of the accepted answer and tried to understand it. I think I do now. Now I wanted to add something that would check if the square would move off the screen. I added that myself as seen here:

*Code inside `Square` class that replaces the `move` method of the copied code:*

```
public void move(Direction dir) {
    if(!(x + step * dir.getIncrX() > GamePanel.getWIDTH() - w) && !(x + step * dir.getIncrX() < 0))
        x += step * dir.getIncrX();
    if(!(y + step * dir.getIncrY() > GamePanel.getHEIGHT() - h) && !(y + step * dir.getIncrY() < 0))
        y += step * dir.getIncrY();
}
```

To achieve this I had to make the constants `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` static and create getters for them. Is the way I created this collision detection good practise? and should the getters for the constants be called `getWidth` and `getHeight` istead of `getWIDTH` and `GetHEIGHT`?

Full code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int ANIMATION_DELAY = 15;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 500;
    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private Square square;
    private EnumMap<Direction, Boolean> dirMap = new EnumMap<>(Direction.class);
    private Map<Integer, Direction> keyToDir = new HashMap<>();

    public GamePanel() {
        for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
            dirMap.put(dir, false);
        }
        keyToDir.put(KeyEvent.VK_UP, Direction.UP);
        keyToDir.put(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, Direction.DOWN);
        keyToDir.put(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, Direction.LEFT);
        keyToDir.put(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, Direction.RIGHT);
        setKeyBindings();
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWIDTH(), getHEIGHT()));
        setFocusable(true);
        square = new Square();
        Timer animationTimer;
        animationTimer = new Timer(ANIMATION_DELAY, new AnimationListener());
        animationTimer.start();
        square.setStep(5);
    }

    public static int getHEIGHT() {
        return HEIGHT;
    }

    public static int getWIDTH() {
        return WIDTH;
    }

    private void setKeyBindings() {
        int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
        final InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
        final ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
        boolean[] keyPressed = { true, false };
        for (Integer keyCode : keyToDir.keySet()) {
            Direction dir = keyToDir.get(keyCode);
            for (boolean onKeyPress : keyPressed) {
                boolean onKeyRelease = !onKeyPress;
                KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, onKeyRelease);
                Object key = keyStroke.toString();
                inputMap.put(keyStroke, key);
                actionMap.put(key, new KeyBindingsAction(dir, onKeyPress));
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        square.display(g);
    }

    private class AnimationListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            boolean repaint = false;
            for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
                if (dirMap.get(dir)) {
                    square.move(dir);
                    repaint = true;
                }
            }
            if (repaint)
                repaint();
        }
    }

    private class KeyBindingsAction extends AbstractAction {
        private Direction dir;
        boolean pressed;

        public KeyBindingsAction(Direction dir, boolean pressed) {
            this.dir = dir;
            this.pressed = pressed;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            dirMap.put(dir, pressed);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GamePanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        gamePanel.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

enum Direction {
    UP(0, -1), DOWN(0, 1), LEFT(-1, 0), RIGHT(1, 0);
    private int incrX;
    private int incrY;

    Direction(int incrX, int incrY) {
        this.incrX = incrX;
        this.incrY = incrY;
    }

    public int getIncrX() {
        return incrX;
    }

    public int getIncrY() {
        return incrY;
    }
}

class Square {
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private int w = 20;
    private int h = w;
    private int step = 1;
    private Color color = Color.red;

    public void display(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setColor(color);
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public void setStep(int step) {
        this.step = step;
    }

    public void move(Direction dir) {
        if(!(x + step * dir.getIncrX() > GamePanel.getWIDTH() - w) && !(x + step * dir.getIncrX() < 0))
            x += step * dir.getIncrX();
        if(!(y + step * dir.getIncrY() > GamePanel.getHEIGHT() - h) && !(y + step * dir.getIncrY() < 0))
            y += step * dir.getIncrY();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the visibility of `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` to `public`, so you can call them by `GamePanel.WIDTH` and `GamePanel.HEIGHT`. Because for `static final` variables you never create Getters!
And you should change your code like this to improve it's performance:

```
public void move(Direction dir) {
    int newX = x + step * dir.getIncrX(), newY = y + step * dir.getIncrY();
    if (!(newX > GamePanel.WIDTH - w) && !(newX < 0)) x = newX;
    if (!(newY > GamePanel.HEIGHT - h) && !(newY < 0)) y = newY;
}
```

Comment: So should I make all static final variables to public by default? And thanks.

Comment: You can, but if you use a variable just in the same class you can make them `private static final`. But if you use them in another class, you should make them `public static final` instead of a Getter.